# Adjust contrast on Windows 7 Laptop

Tags: windows-7, laptop, display, calibration, contrast

**Problem:**
The brightness/contrast on my laptop is way off. There is little conrast and on the maximum brightness everything is just kind of hazy/halo like. Lowering the brightness a little bit doesn't help and quickly makes everything very dark, but still hazy/halo like with no contrast to be able to see borders on windows.

**What I have:**
I have a very cheap HP laptop from work. It says that it is using "AMD A6 VISION".

**Trouble shooting i have done so far**:
There is neither any AMD nor any ATI software installed on this laptop. So there is no OEM software to adjust contrast installed. I followed other guides such as running "DCCW", the default color profile/calibration tool in windows. Ran it, but there is no way that I can change the contrast. I also tried downloading another software that creates a color profile called Calibrize but it appears that these software only adjust the color levels. It is getting annoying when they tell me to "adjust the contrast on my monitors display" during the wizard as well, thus I have come here.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Screenbright](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Desktop-Enhancements/Other-Desktop-Enhancements/ScreenBright.shtml), [Display Tuner](http://www.nicomsoft.com/products/display-tuner/) for brightness adjustment or try [powershell script](http://techibee.com/powershell/powershell-change-monitor-brightness/1022) for [brightness control](http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/powershell/rootwmiset-monitor-brightness/)

```
function Set-MonitorBrighness {
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
[ValidateRange(0,100)]
[int]$brightness
)            

$mymonitor = Get-WmiObject -Namespace rootwmi -Class WmiMonitorBrightnessMethods
$mymonitor.wmisetbrightness(5,$brightness)
}
Set-MonitorBrighness -brightness 1
```

Comment: Great answer, but sadly those software do not work on AMD integrated laptoped based displays.

Comment: Try [this](http://forum.notebookreview.com/hp-envy-hdx/650310-brightness-controls-utility-works-latest-amd-drivers.html) also.